# Can I unpublish a app in play console and upload the same app in other play console account?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I've got 2 suspensions in my google play console. Can i unpublish the existing apps and can i publish it again in another google play console account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't publish an app with the exact same package id. Neither on the same account, nor on another. But you can [transfer the ownership](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en) from one account to another through the Play Store.

Besides that, you can publish the same app with another package id.